# boost::unordered_set intersection using templates

Tags: c++, performance, template, boost, set

I wrote this function to do `unordered_set` intersection using templates. I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/896440/2912901) but I thought that it was overkill. I would like the method to take in 2 sets and return a set.

```
class SetUtilites{
public:
    template<typename Type>
    static boost::unordered_set<Type> intersection(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &set1, const boost::unordered_set<Type> &set2){
        if(set1.size() < set2.size()){

            boost::unordered_set<Type> iSet;

            boost::unordered_set<Type>::iterator it;
            for(it = set1.begin(); it != set1.end();++it){
                if(set2.find(*it) != set2.end()){
                    iSet.insert(*it);
                }
            }
            return iSet;
        }else{
            return intersection(set2,set1);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- `SetUtilites` is misspelled; it should be `SetUtilities`.
- For better readability, consider doing something about this long line:

  > ```
  > static boost::unordered_set<Type> intersection(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &set1, const boost::unordered_set<Type> &set2)
  > ```

  You could shorten the types as such via `typedef`, but it may not help very much, or it may even make things uglier.  You could also wrap the line in some way.  Choose whichever works best.
- Do you even need a `class` for this?  It just contains one function and no data members, so it's not really doing anything relevant as one.  Instead, just make this a free function (non-member function) and put it into a `namespace` with a similar name as the `class`.
- The name `iSet` sort of sounds like Hungarian notation, although it appears to be a shortened form of `intersectionSet`.  If you still don't want to call it something that lengthy, you could rename it to something like `finalSet`, indicating that it will be returned from the function.

Answer (score 8):

### Bug

When your sets are of equal size you well end up in an endless recursion.
Instead of `if(set1.size() < set2.size())` you should use `if(set1.size() <= set2.size())` (after all it does not make much sense to swap if the sets are of equal size).

### Use C++11 loops ...

With C++11 I would advise you to use range based for:

```
for(auto const &element: set1)
```

To avoid having to deal with the element type and with iterators.

### ... or an alternative

I assume you are not using C++11 or you would have taken `std::unordered_set` instead of the boost one.

Even without C++11 there is `BOOST_FOREACH` which you could use:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Type const &element, set1)
```

### Use easier to understand functions

Furthermore I would suggest to use the `count` function so you don't have to compare iterators:

```
if(set2.count(element) > 0)
   iSet.insert(element);
```

### Wrap Up

Finally I would avoid the vertical whitespace that does not add clarity which makes the resulting code (with additions from Jamal's answer):

```
template<typename Type>
static boost::unordered_set<Type> intersection(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &set1, const boost::unordered_set<Type> &set2){
    if(set1.size() <= set2.size()){
        boost::unordered_set<Type> iSet;
        for(auto const &element : set1){
            if(set2.count(element) > 0) {
                iSet.insert(element);
            }
        }
        return iSet;
    }else{
        return intersection(set2,set1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for bug fix. I would guess that count is more expensive than find, no? Comparing against end is common in stl I believe. Your solution is great, but I do not wish to use c++11 features.

Comment: I would say count is internally implemented as end-comparison. End-comparison is a common idiom but still harder to read than count (I believe). In any case it is longer code so it offers more space for errors. Regerding C++11: You can simply transform the C++11 `for` to `BOOST_FOREACH` as I have written and the code should work the same. Explicit iterator loops always have the problem of being very verbose and doing potentially other things than looping over all elements. A foreach does communicate more clearly what it does.

Comment: I agree with the for each point. It is much clearer. I feel a little funny about using count with set because the semantics clash. What I really want would be hasKey or hasElement O(1) of course. I could make another function for that and make it clearer.