# A class for simple and efficient operations on boost::unordered_set

Tags: c++, boost, set

I wrote this class to perform simple template-set operations on `boost::unordered_set`. These operations are part of a larger code base. Calling them will be explicit with `SetUtilities::set_intersection(setA, setB)`.

The main reason I wanted this was to optimize intersection operations (using constant time find in the larger set). After taking to heart the comments from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/simple-and-efficient-boostunordered-set-intersection), I edited the class and provided the rest of the methods.

For now I want to use Boost instead of C++11. I can always do this in the future.

```
#ifndef SET_UTILITIES
#define SET_UTILITIES

#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

class SetUtilities{

public:

    //!set OPERATION intersection for boost::unordered_set
    template<typename Type>
    static boost::unordered_set<Type>
        set_intersection(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setA,
                         const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setB)
    {
        //iterate the smaller set O(n)
        if(setA.size() <= setB.size()){
            boost::unordered_set<Type> intersectionSet;
            BOOST_FOREACH(const Type &element, setA){
                //find element in O(1)
                if(set_hasElement(setB,element)){
                    intersectionSet.insert(element);
                }
            }
            return intersectionSet;
        }else{
            return set_intersection(setB,setA);
        }
    }

    //!set OPERATION union for boost::unordered_set
    template<typename Type>
    static boost::unordered_set<Type> 
        set_union(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setA,
                  const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setB)
    {
        if(setA.size() <= setB.size()){
            boost::unordered_set<Type> unionSet = setB;
            //iterate the smaller set O(n)
            BOOST_FOREACH(const Type &element, setA){
                unionSet.insert(element);
            }
            return unionSet;
        }else{
            return set_union(setB,setA);
        }
    }

    //!set OPERATION difference A - B
    template<typename Type>
    static bool
        set_difference(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setA,
                       const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setB)
    {
        boost::unordered_set<Type> differenceSet;
        //is size are not equal, sets are not equal
        BOOST_FOREACH(const Type &element,setA){
            if(set_hasElement(setB,element) == false){
                differenceSet.insert(element);
            }
        }
        return differenceSet;
    }

    //!set UTILITY funciton to determine if a set contains an element
    template<typename Type>
    static bool
        set_hasElement(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &mySet, 
                       Type element)
    {
        return mySet.find(element) != mySet.end();
    }

    //!set equality test for boost::unordered_set
    template<typename Type>
    static bool 
        are_equal(const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setA,
                  const boost::unordered_set<Type> &setB)
    {
        //is size are not equal, sets are not equal
        if(setA.size() != setB.size()){
            return false;
        }else{
            BOOST_FOREACH(const Type &element, setA){
                if(set_hasElement(setB,element)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

I believe that this version is very readable and explicit. I think that adding `typedef`s with stuff like this in a single class would create more confusion. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fix compiler errors

Your `set_difference` function does not compile. You have declared it returning `bool`, but then `return differenceSet;` in the function body. This is a type mismatch: your function should return a `boost::unordered_set`.

#### Reinventing the wheel

`boost::unordered_set` already supports `operator==` for equality comparison. You don't need to implement it yourself -- your `are_equal()` function is unnecessary.

Additionally, your `set_union` can be simplified. You can replace your foreach-loop:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const Type &element, setA){
            unionSet.insert(element);
        }
```

with using the two-iterator overload of `insert()`:

```
unionSet.insert(setA.begin(), setA.end());
```

This should be no less efficient than what you have already written, and is slightly more readable.

#### Remove irrelevant comments

`set_difference()` contains this comment: `//is size are not equal, sets are not equal`. This has no relevance to what the function actually does. This, combined with the type error listed above, leads me to believe that this is a copy-paste error. When you do that, make sure things like this don't slip through.

#### Boolean comparison

You don't need to explicitly compare Boolean conditions against `false`:

```
if(set_hasElement(setB,element) == false)
```

Can be more succinctly stated:

```
if(!set_hasElement(setB,element))
```

#### Naming

This is a minor nitpick, but `set_hasElement` combines `underscore_separated` and `CamelCase` capitalization conventions. I would rename it to `set_contains()` for name consistency with the rest of your functions.

#### Namespaces

Creating a class with only public `static` functions is very Java-esque. C++ allows namespaces, which are a way of organizing functions and classes. Your set functions might be better as free functions placed in a `namespace SetUtilities` instead of a class.

Comment: Good point about the last thing.  With no data members, and especially everything `public`, a `class` is not needed (not even a `struct`).

Comment: Good points. I just wrote this today to address comments in the other questions and it lead to errors with difference which I didn't really need. It should return a set not a bool. I put it as == false to be more explicit and appease the readability nazi's. I like ! better as well. Good point about namespace. I wanted a static class like java but namespace is a better fit.